# Not able to mock urllib2.urlopen using Python's mock.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, urllib2, python-mock

Below is a code snippet of my api.py module

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib2 import Request

class API:

    def call_api(self, url, post_data=None, header=None):
        is_post_request = True if (post_data and header) else False
        response = None
        try:
            if is_post_request:
                url = Request(url = url, data = post_data, headers = header)
            # Calling api
            api_response = urlopen(url)
            response = api_response.read()
        except Exception as err:
            response = err

        return response
```

I am trying to mock `urllib2.urlopen` in `unittest` of above module. I have written

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# test_api.py

from unittest import TestCase
import mock

from api import API

class TestAPI(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('urllib2.Request')
    @mock.patch('urllib2.urlopen')
    def test_call_api(self, urlopen, Request):
        urlopen.read.return_value = 'mocked'
        Request.get_host.return_value = 'google.com'
        Request.type.return_value = 'https'
        Request.data = {}
        _api = API()
        assert _api.call_api('https://google.com') == 'mocked'
```

After I run the unittest, I get an exception

```
<urlopen error unknown url type: <MagicMock name='Request().get_type()' id='159846220'>>
```

What am I missing? Please help me out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are patching the wrong things: take a look to [Where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

In `api.py` by

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib2 import Request
```

you create a local reference to `urlopen` and `Request` in your file. By `mock.patch('urllib2.urlopen')` you are patching the original reference and leave the `api.py`'s one untouched.

So, replace your patches by

```
@mock.patch('api.Request')
@mock.patch('api.urlopen')
```

should fix your issue.... but is not enough.

In your test case `api.Request` are not used but `urllib2.urlopen()` create a `Request` by use the patched version: that is why `Request().get_type()` is a `MagicMock`.

For a complete fix you should change your test at all. First the code:

```
@mock.patch('api.urlopen', autospec=True)
def test_call_api(self, urlopen):
    urlopen.return_value.read.return_value = 'mocked'
    _api = API()
    self.assertEqual(_api.call_api('https://google.com'), 'mocked')
    urlopen.assert_called_with('https://google.com')
```

Now the clarification... In your test you don't call `Request()` because you pass just the first parameter, so I've removed useless patch. Moreover you are patching `urlopen` function and not `urlopen` object, that means the `read()` method you want mocked is a method of the object return by `urlopen()` call.

Finally I add a check on `urlopen` call and [`autospec=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing) that is always a good practice.

Comment: I made the changes. The value of `_api.call_api('https://google.com')`  is `<MagicMock name='urlopen().read()' id='3069563372'>` which doesn't match "mocked". Why? P.S. I have updated last line with `assert` in test_api.py

Comment: @Hussain now it should be OK

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. Great insight on mock patching. I guess I can make some changes and make it work for `requests` too